# SharePoint Designer Worflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer-workflow, send-email

I'm fairly new to SharePoint designer and I am trying to create a workflow that will send an automatic email whenever I create a new document in a specific folder in SharePoint 2013.

Getting SharePoint to send an automatic email is not the issue, the issue is I have 15 folders and each folder has the same file that gets updated automatically every other day.

With that being said, I'm getting the same 15 emails all the time.  What I would like is for SharePoint to just send one email versus 15.  Can anyone tell me how I can do that?

Here is the formula that I used to get SharePoint to send an automatic email every time a new item is created:

```
If Current Item:Created equals created
 then Email these users
```

But this generates a new email every time a new item is created in each of the 15 folders.  I just need one email to be sent.  I tried to use the following formula:

```
If Current Item:Created equals value
  then Email these users
```

But I need to change value to a specific file name.  Please advise.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you create a new document, add additional metadata in the library. I have given the steps below.

**Example:**

1. Add Yes/No data type field in the library and named it **Send an
   Email**(Default value **NO**)
2. When you create a new document, you should change the field **Send an
   Email** value to **Yes**
3. In the workflow you should add these condition and send an email to users **If Current Item:SendanEmail** equals **Yes** then Email these users

Comment: If the above answer is satisfying your question then, please accept it so it will help the other people.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just one email to be sent, You need to add conditions to limit whether to send e-mails.